# Change color of () and [] in VS2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text, colors

I'm quite familiar with Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors. I have a highly customized color scheme in VS2010. My question is this: Can I change the color of `parentheses` and `square brackets` (not curly braces) without changing the color of Plain Text (the group under which these characters reside).